# Defining TableSchema in PubSubToBigQuery template

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm having trouble specifying a TableSchema in Google's Dataflow template for for reading a pub-sub subscription and streaming into BigQuery.
Template provided here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java

Per documentation here - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#creating-a-table-schema

I attempted to add TableSchema to match my destination in BigQuery

```
/** Define Table Schema */
TableSchema schema = new TableSchema()
    .setFields(
        ImmutableList.of(
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("device_id")
                .setType("STRING")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("timestamp")
                .setType("TIMESTAMP")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("orientation")
                .setType("FLOAT")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("orientation")
                .setType("STRING")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("light_level")
                .setType("FLOAT")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("temperature")
                .setType("FLOAT")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("button_pressed")
                .setType("BOOLEAN")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("city")
                .setType("STRING")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
                new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("region")
                .setType("string")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("lat")
                .setType("STRING")
                .setMode("NULLABLE"),
            new TableFieldSchema()
                .setName("long")
                .setType("string")
                .setMode("NULLABLE")));
```

Here's the error I get when trying to compile.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project google-cloud-teleport-java: Compilation
>   failure [ERROR]
>   /home/jquattlebaum/DataflowTemplates/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java:[131,5]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class TableSchema [ERROR]
>   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery

Comment: I see in your code your are using both lowercase string and upper case STRING. can you try only uppercase and advice if you see any change

Answer (score 0):

Something like this usually happens when you don't have a dependency setup correctly. I.e. your project (template) has to declare a dependency that has the definition of `TableSchema` and then you have to add a corresponding import statement in your java file (`PubSubToBigQuery.java`).

Dependency declaration likely happens in `pom.xml` and if you haven't modified it much, it should already include the correct dependency for `TableSchema`, the `google-api-services-bigquery` library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/pom.xml#L258.

If it does, then make sure you have `import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema` at the top of `PubSubToBigQuery.java`.

Then make sure you do `mvn clean` or clean the project from the IDE before building it again.

If this does not help I would look for a typo somewhere.